# Can I access a full composer package from a link when responding to an event

Tags: composer-php

I have created an event handler to be called by composer when processing `composer.json`:

```
"post-install-cmd": [
    "Company\\Library\\Layer\\Handler::script"
],
```

The relevant, corresponding code is:

```
class Handler {
    public static function script(Event $event) {
        $aRequires = $event->getComposer()->getPackage()->getRequires();
        foreach ($aRequires as $oRequire) {
            // process each required package
        }
    }
}
```

Each `$oRequire` is of type `Composer\Package\Link` and contains basic information about the required package.

I'd like to be able to access the full package information, eg. a sub-class of `Composer\Package\BasePackage`. Is this possible? That is, given a `Link` and the target name, can I lookup (resolve?) the target name to its full package in this context?

I've read a fair bit of the doco and I cannot tell either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After earning the [Tumbleweed badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed) for this question, I decided it need an answer. Obviously no-one came forward with a solution and despite further effort on my part, I could not find one either. So I conclude there is no direct way to achieve what I want.

The information I'm after however, is in the `composer.lock` file. So if this file has been successfully created, you could load it (it's JSON, so this is trivial) and then lookup the desired info.